# I'm able to access router panel on 192.168.100.1, although I don't see such network in ipconfig

Tags: networking, ip, router

I am able to access the router's administration panel at `http://192.168.100.1/logon.html`.

`ipconfig` returns this:

```
$ ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter vEthernet (External Switch 1):

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : toya.net.pl
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.3.156.105
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.248.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.3.152.1

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.78.168
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.86.18
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.18.91.161
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

How am I able to access `192.168.100.1` if there is no such network returned by `ipconfig`? Why I don't see that network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the WAN interface on your router. You can get to it because the traffic goes to your Default Gateway, which is the router.

Comment: Could you share some resource where I could learn more about that?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/TCP-Illustrated-Vol-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0201633469

Comment: You get to that address just like you get to any other address on the Internet, including this site.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.100.1 is often the ISP modem private IP.

It's why that network don't show on your LAN routing table, but it's a private IP on the WAN's side.

See that example from my modem at home;

[image]